# In Silverlight, can one define min/max values for a DependencyProperty?

Tags: silverlight, dependency-properties, unsigned

For example, I have a dependency property that changes the ScaleTransform of a Canvas, but if it ever goes below zero it throws an error. Sure, I could just force it to zero in the code if that ever happens, but I'd rather use a better method like using a udouble (unsigned double), which doesn't exist in Silverlight or even setting the min/max values somewhere in the DependencyProperty.

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to handle this in your DependencyProperty, I'd recommend handling it in a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903933(VS.95).aspx), which validates that the value is in the correct range and overrides it if not.

You could also handle this outside of the dependency property. For instance:

- A [value converter](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx)
- Enforcing this in the model, and binding to a ViewModel which always has a valid value. See [more about MVVM here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd458800.aspx).

Comment: That's what I ended up doing – changing it in the PropertyChangedCallback, but I was looking for an alternative. Thanks for the extra links here.

Comment: Would you post an example of how you can safely/cleanly override the value that was just changed? If you change it, it would fire the whole OnChanged event/callback a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to that, inside your PropertyChangedCallback, a typical pattern is going to be revert on incorrect/out-of-range values, before throwing an exception.

If you don't do the revert, the out-of-range value will actually still be set, and your state will be invalid.

You'll see examples of this "poor man's coercian" in some of the Silverlight Toolkit. Here's the [AutoCompleteBox.cs source](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/25992?projectName=Silverlight#639539).

The pattern is something like:

```
   int newValue = (int)e.NewValue;
        if (newValue < 0)
        {
            source._ignorePropertyChange = true;
            d.SetValue(e.Property, e.OldValue);

            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Properties.Resources.AutoComplete_OnMinimumPopulateDelayPropertyChanged_InvalidValue, newValue), "value");
        }
```

You can also implement your own "read-only" Silverlight dependency properties in a similar manner, though it'll require a private field to indicate whether you're setting or reverting the value.